# DSP questions: best here, or on dsp.se?

Tags: discussion

Lately I've been working on some digital decoders for PSK31 and RTTY. Many signal processing questions come to mind, regarding filtering, equalization, channel coding, and so on. Examples:

- [Applying Viterbi algorithm to compensate for ISI in PSK31](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/41655/4030)
- [Determining pulse shape for Viterbi Equalization](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/41684/4030)
- [Filtering for PSK31 demodulation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/7703/218)

Should I ask those questions here? Or on dsp.stackexchange.com? I don't think they'd be strictly off topic in either place, yet there's still a question of the more appropriate forum.

On one hand, these questions are mostly about signal processing, and it just happens to be the signal in question is used in amateur radio. Of all hams, those well-versed in signal processing algorithms are a small subset, and I'll probably get a more knowledgeable (for the particular problem) set of people reading my question on DSP.se. (Though anecdotally, DSP.se hasn't been especially helpful for me so far.)

On the other hand, these modes are very relevant to hams. Among DSP, RF communication is a specialization. And even among that, HF communications (my particular area of interest) is far more common in amateur radio than it is in the RF communication community generally.

Ostensibly, hams are involved in the understanding of these modes, their implementation, and improvement thereof; and the development of new modes or techniques on existing modes with improved performance. I believe this isn't really the case, and current practice in amateur radio is years to decades behind common practice everywhere else, most of the common digital modes are anachronistic, and in some cases outright poorly designed. But if I want to change that, shouldn't conversation be in the amateur radio community?

Comment: That's a great question. I suggest that you ask at least some questions on dsp.se and see what kind of answers you get. Also, I've never read that cross-posting is always a no-no on SE; if it is, then perhaps let the folks on ham.se know about your post in dsp.SE, either in your question or in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where no ideal solution exists. If I had free reign to change the system to help, I would arrange so that a question could be mirrored from one site to another. (Not read-write on both sites, because then you have the problem of trying to simultaneously meet two sites' standards.)

The best you can do to share knowledge widely, under a strict interpretation of the rules, is to ask questions on whichever site is the best individual fit, and include links to your questions on the other site whenever they are relevant context.

(I think you've done a good job of picking sites for your example questions.)

I think it would be okay *in moderation* to repost a question *with answer, edited to suit,* here once you've gotten an answer from the DSP experts. The intent of the rule against reposting questions is, in my understanding, to avoid duplicating work among answerers, and if the question is self-answered then that doesn't apply.